# How to return the index of a slected row of ag-grid

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I want to get the index of a selected row in ag-grid and there's a button to add a row above or below that selected row. I know there's way to print the clicked row index in the console, which is to add the following code into gridOptions:

```
onRowClick(event: any): void {
  console.log(event.rowIndex);
}
```

But I cannot get the value from console and return this row index.

Please help me in this.

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint on ``console.log(event.rowIndex);``, hovered over the ``event`` property to make sure you are accessing the row index correctly and that the event is firing ``onRowClick()``?

Comment: Yes, I can see the value in console, but what I want is similar to assign the value to a variable.

Comment: Well the rowIndex will come across as an object, not really a string that can be written to console. If it has the values you want, you should then be able to use the rowIndex wherever. Complex objects aren't going to write to the console like that really.